# My setInterval is generating error "2VM6:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: timer is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1"

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, setinterval

I am tying to display time (hour, minute, seconds) in a mini-calculator but am receiving 
an unusual error message:

> {2VM6:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: timer is not defined
>   at :1:1}.

I  think that `setInterval` method is causing that error, my script is below I believe that the error is from there:

````
 ```<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css"/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="time">chinaza</div>
            <div class="item_1" id="display_container"></div>
            <div class="item_1" id="result"></div>
            <div class="item_1" id="key_container">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>del</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>/</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>.</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>=</td>
                        <td>+</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    window.onload=function(){
        function timer(){
            let time =new Date();
            let hour=time.getHours();
            let min=time.getMinutes();
            let sec=time.getSeconds();
            console.log(hour,min,sec);
            document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=sec;
        }
        setInterval("timer()",1000);
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to pass timer like that in quotes.  Here's a working pen you should be able to use:

```js
window.onload=function(){
  function timer(){
    let time =new Date();
    let hour=time.getHours();
    let min=time.getMinutes();
    let sec=time.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=sec;
  }
  window.setInterval(function() { timer() },1000);
};
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: You are a genius it worked, please explain what you did.

Comment: First, you were passing the function in quotes like so: `setInterval("timer()",1000)`, and you don't want to put quotes around it.  If I only removed the quotes like this: `setInterval(timer(),1000)`, then I would only be passing the result of the call to `timer()` function to setInterval.  Instead, in my answer, I am passing your timer() **as a function** to setInterval, which instructs `setInterval` to call it every second in this case.  Please upvote the answer since it satisfied your needs, and let me know if this comment doesn't explain what you are asking well enough.  Thanks!